# How to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow n^-}e^{\frac{n}{x-n}} = 0$ using a $\delta-\varepsilon$ proof.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to prove that $e^{\frac{n}{x-n}}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow n^-$ where $n>0$ using a $\delta-\varepsilon$ proof. Here's what I've got thus far.

$\mid e^{\frac{n}{x-n}} \mid = e^{\frac{n}{x-n}} < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow \frac{n}{x-n} < \ln(\varepsilon) \stackrel{x<n}{\Leftrightarrow} n > (x-n)\ln(\varepsilon) \Leftrightarrow -n<(n-x)\ln(\varepsilon) \stackrel{0<\varepsilon<1}{\Leftrightarrow} -\frac{n}{\ln(\varepsilon)}>n-x \stackrel{x<n}{=} \mid x-n \mid$. Thus if we let $0<\varepsilon<1$  then we can set $\delta = -\frac{n}{\ln(\varepsilon)}$. When $\varepsilon\geq1$ I don't know what to do. How do I find a $\delta$ for that case?

Comment: Don't ever select an epsilon greater than 1.  Or in other words.  If $\epsilon < 1$ select the delta you gave.  If $\epsilon \ge 1$ select $\delta = -\frac {n}{\ln .5}$ then $|e^{\frac n{x-n}}| < .5 < 1 \le \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, it is not restrictive to consider only "small" values of $\epsilon$. In your case $0<\epsilon<1$ is good. If you prove the statement for any $\epsilon$ small, the same statement will trivially hold for $\epsilon$ "large", since $\epsilon < \epsilon+ h$ for every $h > 0$.

Comment: But in my computation I found that if $\varepsilon > 1$ then the $\delta$ that I picked for when $0<\varepsilon < 1$ is no longer sufficient since it is then smaller than $\mid x-n \mid$. Your argument makes sense to me yet my calculations say that $\delta$ cannot be used, how come? For $\varepsilon = 1$ that delta is not even defined.

Comment: So, you want $\epsilon \geq 1$. Consider the number $\delta$ that you have found in correspondence with $\epsilon=1/2$. Then, whenever $|x-n|<\delta$, you have $e^{\frac{x}{x-n}}<1/2<\epsilon$. You are done.

Answer (score 1):

If you find a $\delta$ that shows $n-x < \delta \implies f(x) < \epsilon_1 < 1$.  Then if $\epsilon_2 \ge 1$, the *same* $\delta$ will show $n-x < \delta \implies f(x) < \epsilon_1 < 1 \le \epsilon_2$.

It is *perfectly* valid to say, "we will restrict ourselves only to $\epsilon$s less than $c$"  (It is NOT okay to say we will restrict ourselves to $\epsilon$s larger than $c$") or to say "since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small we may assume $0 < \epsilon < 10^{-5,000}$".  Those are *FINE* statements.

If you don't feel comfortable with that you can say.  "If $\epsilon < 1$ this works.  If $\epsilon \ge 1$ we can replace $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon_2$ so that $0 < \epsilon_2 < 1 \le \epsilon$."

Or as $\delta$ is a value dependent upon $\epsilon$ you think of it as a function.  $\delta_{\epsilon} = - \frac n{\ln(\epsilon)}$.  If we need the the input to be $\le 1$ but we dont know if $\epsilon$ is we can say $\delta_{\min(\epsilon, \frac 12)}$. That will prove if $n - x < \delta$ then *BOTH*  $f(x) < \frac 12$ and $f(x) < \epsilon$.  If $\epsilon \ge 1$ then $f(x) < \frac 12 < \epsilon$.

Perfectly valid.